# Issues displaying uploaded .PNG images transparent

Tags: php

i just finaly managed to get user uploaded images to stay transparent, when they are png, by doing this:

```
    $image_p = imagecreatetruecolor($fixed_width, $fixed_height);

    if ($_FILES[$fileName]["type"] == "image/x-png" || $_FILES[$fileName]["type"] == "image/png") {

        $background = imagecolorallocate($image_p, 0, 0, 0);
        imagecolortransparent($image_p, $background);
        imagealphablending($image_p, false);
        imagesavealpha($image_p, true);
    }

    // PNG or JPG
    if ($_FILES[$fileName]["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES[$fileName]["type"] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES[$fileName]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($imageFile);
    } else {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($imageFile);
    }


    // check if img is bigger then max width
    $manipulated = 0;

    if ($width_orig > $fixed_width) {
        imagecopyresampled($image_p, $image, 0, 0, 0, 0, $fixed_width, $fixed_height, $width_orig, $height_orig); // reduce in width / height
        $manipulated = 1;
    } else {
        $image_p = $image; // leave as is
    }

    // Output PNG or JPG
    if ($_FILES[$fileName]["type"] == "image/jpeg" || $_FILES[$fileName]["type"] == "image/jpg" || $_FILES[$fileName]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") {
        imagejpeg($image_p, $newfile, 65);
    } else {
        imagepng($image_p, $newfile, 6);
    }
```

But now i have issues displaying them as .png, when i open the file from the Cpanel dictionary, it is transparent, but when i display it with:

```
<?php

$file = basename(urldecode($_GET['img']));
$file = str_replace("../", "", $file); 

$fileDir = '/home/funkydic/noaccess/avatars/';

$jpg = strpos($file, '.jpg');
$jpeg = strpos($file, '.jpeg');
$png = strpos($file, '.png');

if ($jpg != false || $jpeg != false) {

    if (file_exists($fileDir . $file)) {

        $imageRes = imagecreatefromjpeg($fileDir . $file);
        header('Content-Type: image/jpeg');
        // Output the image
        @imagepng($imageRes);
        // Free up memory
        @imagedestroy($imageRes);
        die();
    }
}
elseif ($png != false) {

    if (file_exists($fileDir . $file)) {


        $imageRes = imagecreatefrompng($fileDir . $file);

        header('Content-Type: image/png');
        // Output the image
        @imagepng($imageRes);
        // Free up memory
        @imagedestroy($imageRes);
        die();
    }
}
?>
```

The black box returns, at the transparent area.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: How do i preserve transparency when displaying the image

Comment: I think if you set some elements background-image, it will be transparent.

Comment: What was your original problem? That a .png would not preserve its transparency when uploaded through a form by the user?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Issues with preserving image transparency, have tried alot of options mentioned on stackoverflow](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16575206/issues-with-preserving-image-transparency-have-tried-alot-of-options-mentioned)

Comment: Hmm, you posted your [last question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/16570464/472495) twice, and you seem now to have done it with this question too. Remember that when you ask a question many times, you risk causing duplicate effort for someone - please don't do it.

Answer (score 0):

If you already have a PNG that you just want to send to the browser, you don't need GD for that.

```php
header('Content-Type: image/png');
fp = fopen($fileDir . $file, "r");
fpassthru($fp);
fclose($fp); /* this is not necessary, but I prefer to keep it */
exit();
```

Since you export your JPEGs the same way (btw, you have an error in that part: header says `image/jpeg` and you're sending a PNG with `@imagepng()`), I'd rewrite your code like this:

```
<?php

$allowedMimes = array("png", "gif", "jpeg");
$fileDir = '/home/funkydic/noaccess/avatars/';

$file = basename(urldecode($_GET['img']));
$file = str_replace("../", "", $file); /* what's this for? you already have basename() */

if (file_exists($fileDir . $file)) {
    $mime = strtolow(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION));
    if ($mime == "jpg") $mime = "jpeg";

    if (in_array($mime, $allowedMimes)) {
        header("Content-Type: image/$mime");
        fp = fopen($fileDir . $file, "r");
        fpassthru($fp);
        fclose($fp);
        exit();
    }
    /* if you get here, extension in the GET request was wrong */
}
/* if you get here, extension in the GET request was wrong or the file doesn't exist */
?>
```